# How do I set up an environment for developing Mono C# iPhone apps on Linux?

Tags: c#, ios, linux, xamarin, development-environment

How do I set up a development environment / IDE for Mono C# iPhone apps on Linux? I seem to be stumped. I have heard that you can use **Xamarin**, but there doesn't seem to be a Linux version. [Xamarin.com](http://xamarin.com/) redirects to a [Microsoft VS download page](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/xamarin/) with only a Windows download link.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318371/how-to-write-applications-for-different-platforms-linux-mac-windows-and-mobil) which asks about developing cross-platform applications but does not specifically mention using Linux as a development environment. Additionally, the links in the top answer are both dead. I searched for **MonoTouch** and found [this Xamarin site](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/ios/monotouch_6/monotouch_6.0/), so it seems to be a part of Xamarin, which doesn't seem to be available for Linux...

I also thought I may be able to develop an iPhone app using **MonoDevelop**, which I already have installed and have used to develop Linux applications on Linux for Linux. I can't seem to find any articles online about how to do this. The "Portable Library" project template in MonoDevelop mentions support for "Xamarin.iOS", but I don't want a library, I want a GUI app.

Comment: Xamarin iOS tools are not supported on Linux.

Comment: So, are there alternatives for C# development for iPhone on Linux?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of